# Loop A Boolean In C++

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm new to C++ and currently running my codes through Code::Blocks
So, I want to ask, how to repeat same code when user's put No in this code :

```
if (first == "No" )
{
    cout << "\nPlease Re-enter Your Name. \n";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\nPlease Re-enter Your Age. \n";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "\nPlease Re-select Your Class. \n";
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Classes" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Advanced" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(5) << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Mage" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Sorceress" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(5) << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Fighter" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Warrior" << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Ninja" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Assassin" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(5) << endl;
    cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;

    cout << "\n";
    cin >> str_class;
    if (str_class == "Mage" )
    {
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Name" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Class" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << "Age" << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << name << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << str_class << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << age << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    }

    if (str_class == "Fighter")
    {
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Name" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Class" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << "Age" << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << name << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << str_class << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << age << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    }

    if (str_class == "Ninja")
    {
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Name" << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << "Class" << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << "Age" << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
        cout << setfill(' ') << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << name << setw(1) << "|" << setw(15) << left << str_class << setw(1) << "|"  << setw(15) << age << setw(1) << "|" << endl;
        cout << setfill('-') << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << setw(15) << "-" << setw(1) << "+" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Your Profile Has Been Changed. \nDo You Want This Profile To Be Sent To The Academy Database ? (Yes/No) \n";
    cin >> first;
}
```

How to change this so that every time the user said No, it repeat this code?

Comment: while loops...........?

Comment: Also look into functions. You can use them to get rid of a lot of repeated code.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation....I'm just starting to learn function last night

Answer (score -1):

Use a while statement, while first is equal to No then keep running through the loop.When they enter No again, it will keep the user in the loop and rerun the code in the while loop.

```
    while (first == "No" )
            {
...
    cout << "Your Profile Has Been Changed. \nDo You Want This Profile To Be Sent To The Academy Database ? (Yes/No) \n";
                cin >> first;

        }
```

Comment: Oh I forgot about that, i keep thinking the for loops...thanks

Comment: Who ever felt it necessary to downvote my answer, please explain yourself.

Comment: Sometimes people will downvote to protest an answer to what they consider a bad question.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, the answer is what the user was looking for though. Anyways i'm over it, lol.